# Matlab: How do I remove rows that contain any of the numbers stored in a vector?

Tags: matlab

I have 163x2 matrix called **A**, and a 15x1 vector called **delindex**.
Now I want to delete every row from A, that has any of the numbers stored in delindex as a value in the first row.

short example:

A =

```
           1       29292
           2       44652
           3       56569
           4       68909
           5       81053
           6       93343
         101      105585
         102      118870
         103      132163
           7      144257
         104      156616
           8      205344
           9      216865
         105      228979
         106      229307
         107      240849
         108      253306
```

And my delindex =

```
4
101
7
105
```

(And for possible future implications: how do I do the same for other rows, in this example the seconde one?)

I have looked up removerows and the any() function, but can't get them to work for me. I'm totally new to matlab and programming, so a place to look in documentation on this might help me as well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error: Matrix dimension must agree.

Comment: Here ist something that works, although I don't quite get the way it works:

`for i = 1:size(delindex,1)
    del = IBP==delindex(i);
    A(del,:)=[]
end`

del is a matrix of the size of A, with only "true" (=1) values where the condition is true. How does this work to adress the corresponding rows in A? (Where do I read to understand this?)

Comment: If you posted code which I could cut and paste into a Matlab session I'd investigate; as it is I'm not going to cut and paste your definition of `A` and then insert all the punctuation that your snippets would need to make them syntactically valid inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) (@Prashant's suggestion):

```
ia = ismember(A(:,1), delindex);
```

Or [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
[~,ia,~] = intersect(A(:,1), delindex);
```

To find which rows should be removed.
Then remove the rows:

```
A(ia,:) = []
```

**Note**

[`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) returns **logical indices**, while in `[C,ia,ib] =`[`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)`(A,B)`, `ia` and `ib` are indices.

Both could be used for indexing. For more info read [***Matrix Indexing in MATLAB***](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).

Comment: Why does [~,ia,~] = intersec... give me the index-numbers of the lines that match, and c = intersec... the actual values? What basic syntax am I not understanding, when I don't get this?

Comment: `ia = ismember(A(:,1), delindex);` Also works, it behaves the same as what pm89 wrote.

Comment: Consider the example in the docs, [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btcnv0p-11). The `~` allow you to ignore positional arguments, to retrieve the second value without having to save the first.

Comment: @Prashant: Yeah it actually seems neater. Would you mind if I update my answer? ;)

Comment: @Lasse: Many functions in Matlab could have more than one output. The all possible ways (`syntaxes`) are shown in documentation of each command. In this case if you ask only one output from `intersect` command it will give you the common set, but you also need the indices. This is why you might want to choose the third syntax.

Comment: One last question: where can I read, why the vector with 0s and 1s can actually be used in A(ia,:) = []; to delete the lines.. as I see it, it just changes between A(1,:) and A(0,:), but that would delete only the first row?!

Comment: Refer to **Logical Indexing** in [***Matrix Indexing in MATLAB***](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).